# Why canvas in onDraw function is only working first time inside timertask's run method?

Tags: android, user-interface, canvas, timertask, ondraw

This is my code in onDraw method.The run method keeps running and I have checked it but canvas is drawing only the first circle , not any more.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int t=0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Your logic here...
                if(!st.empty()){
                    tmp=st.pop();
                }
                System.out.println(""+tmp.col  );
                canvas.drawCircle((tmp.col*cellsize+(tmp.col+1)*cellsize)/2 , (tmp.row*cellsize+(tmp.row+1)*cellsize)/2 , 10 , player);
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Assuming that `canvas` in your snippet is the `Canvas` passed into `onDraw()`, that `Canvas` instance is only valid for the duration of that particular run of `onDraw()`. You cannot use it after the method has completed. Your `schedule()` call has a `0` initial delay, so the first run is apparently happening before that completes, but each subsequent one will be well after that, so they are failing.

Comment: Thanks but what is the solution if I want to draw circle after one seconds each?

Comment: UI hangs if I place a while loop at the end of `onDraw()` to keep the onDraw function running for some time more

Comment: You can't do that, either. `View` changes like that are usually handled by modifying some internal state, and then triggering a redraw. Your `onDraw()` method should be set up so that it is able to draw every possible state; e.g., set up to loop over a resizable list. As an example, here's a custom `View` for a recent similar question: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tHpJWbZB43NZl1uCiKMDDU6COpP5tKBT. That's adding rectangles instead of circles, but you can see how the `addLabel()` method modifies the list, and the triggers a redraw. Structure your `View` like that, then move the `Timer`...

Comment: ...to the `Activity`, and schedule it to simply call your `addCircle()` method, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike.It's been really helpul